# With regex how do i match between an XML tag multiple times?

Tags: javascript, xml, regex, parsing, rss

First, before you say anything, i HAVE to do this because the RSS is malformed, but i can't correct it on my end. So, while I tried using an RSS and a XML parser, they fail and i only have front end access. However, i'm super close, but i can't figure out why this wont match.

The feed (it's a **long** 1 line string):
http://pastebin.com/5dJhXCvf

First Example:

```
<title>(.+)</title>
```

This i thought worked great with my test of just:

```
<title>&quot;cterrorism task force&quot; location:oregon - Google News</title>
```

But the issue is that it matches everything then as one match for example:

```
<title>&quot;cterrorism task force&quot; location:oregon - Google News</title><title>&quot;cterrorism task force&quot; location:oregon - Google News</title>
```

Equals 1 result item in my array from `exec()` and `match()`

So i tried:

```
<title>([\w\d\s\=\%\_\`\~\+\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\:\'\"\[\]\{\}\|\,\.\/]+)</title>
```

But that returns nothing... Any ideas?

Comment: What's malformed about the feed?

Comment: If you copy and paste that into the W3C validator it fails. And jQuery wont even attempt to parse it either. I also tried jFeed but that didn't work either. However, if i call it with a text HEADER it returns fine. I only need the title and links so i figured i could just parse as text then use regex.

Comment: Your character class is missing a few characters, which was pretty well inevitable with a monster like that.  If you want a character class that matches anything but angle brackets, use this: `[^<>]`

Comment: Friends don't let friends parse XML with regexes.

Comment: @orangepips I know, i know, but its *literally* for the mayor and this is the XML he is giving me to use.

Comment: @Oscar Godson: Please check @Laurence Gonsalves [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341421/with-regex-how-do-i-match-between-an-xml-tag-multiple-times/4341631#4341631). It looks like you have a wellformed XML document. Use XPath or any other standar XML tool.

Comment: See my comment to "Mark Thomas" below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try non-greedy version `<title>(.+?)<\/title>`.  [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) you can test these things online.

Comment: `/<title>(.+?)<\/title>/g` is great, however it's only returning 2 results. Do you know why this would be? I believe there should be like 9...

Comment: Not sure.  Are there any new lines in your text?

Comment: Shouldnt be... but there could be

Comment: Maybe it doesn't handle `\n` correctly.  I don't have any other ideas at the moment.  Try adding `m` and/or `i` flags.

Comment: @Oscar try `<title>([^<]+?)</title>`

Comment: @Oscar: This works fine in EditPadPro; I get nine hits.  The `m` and `i` modifiers shouldn't do anything: the regex doesn't contain any anchors, and the tag names are always lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

The RSS you posted is well-formed XML, but not valid RSS (according to the W3C feed validator). Since it's well-formed your best bet is still to use an XML parser, not to use a regex. In fact, most RSS parsers should be ok too, as RSS is kind of notorious for having validation issues (partly due to poor specifications early on), so any RSS parser worth using shouldn't have any trouble with the kinds of validation problems the W3C validator is reporting.

As an aside, that looks like a Google News feed. You can get valid Atom by changing the output parameter from "rss" to "atom". eg:

```
http://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=us&hl=en&topic=h&num=3&output=atom
```

Google's services that generate feeds generally do a better job at producing Atom rather than RSS. That said, you may also want to report the invalid RSS to Google.

Answer (score 1):

Try a lazy quantifier:

```
<title>([^<]+?)</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try an ungreedy expression by adding the U flag:

```
"/<title>(.+)</title>/U"
```

This tells it to match on the smallest match rather than the largest match available.

Answer (score 0):

Many parsers can handle slight deviations from the specs. Any binding to the excellent [libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/) library would be able to handle poorly formed XML. There are bindings in many languages. For example, the following Ruby snippet parses it just fine:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = open('rss.txt').read
doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(xml)
doc.xpath('//title').each do |title|
  puts title.inner_text
end
```

Result:

```
"joint terrorism task force" location:oregon - Google News
"joint terrorism task force" location:oregon - Google News
Federal and FBI Joint Terrorism Task Force are still flawed - OregonLive.com
Striking a fair balance - OregonLive.com
Blame the terrorists, not the FBI - Portland Tribune
Why Oregon? Why not?: Terrorism can strike anywhere - The Register-Guard
INDIVIDUAL TRAVEL UNDER ATTACK - NewsWithViews.com
The other terrorism-and pondering Portland - BlueOregon
Fla. dance troupe causes scare at Lincoln Tunnel - Northwest Cable News
```

Edit: based on your comments I see you're using jQuery. You should be able to use a jQuery XML parser to extract the titles (and other parts, as needed).

Comment: The jQuery XML parser fails silently. When parsed as XML, i get a return of the XML in web inspector, but the actual returned value is `null`. If i ask for it in raw text, it comes back fine. Thats why i was regexing.