# Parsing XML in JavaScript using RegExp and exec - it usually works, but in a few cases it doesn't - any idea why?

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

I am parsing some XML in server-side JavaScript. The XML is returned by a call to another server. I'm using a modified version of a solution I found at [With regex how do i match between an XML tag multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341421/with-regex-how-do-i-match-between-an-xml-tag-multiple-times) and tested the RegExp with the tester at http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html.

There are some 1280 records returned, and it works almost all the time. But I noticed today that about 30 records don't parse correctly. Some fields end up null when parsed and I can't figure out why.

A sample of a regular expression I'm creating in a loop is

```
<field name="URL_ProProfs"><data>(.+?)<\/data><\/field>
```

And an example of a record I'm parsing is

```
<record mod-id="439" record-id="6640">
    <field name="Name">
        <data>Inviting Young Children to Explore Process Art</data>
    </field>
    <field name="Byline_Presenter">
        <data> Presented by MaryAnn F. Kohl, Author, Educator, and Presenter </data>
    </field>
    <field name="Date">
        <data>11/14/2016</data>
    </field>
    <field name="URL_On_Demand">
        <data> https://www.anymeeting.com/843-066-411/E954DB85814B38 </data>
    </field>
    <field name="URL_ProProfs">
        <data> https://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/story.php?title=quiz-18-classroommanagementwebinar20161114_3WO </data>
    </field>
    <field name="Status">
        <data>1</data>
    </field>
    <field name="URL_Blog">
        <data> http://home.edweb.net/webinar/young-children-explore-process-art/ </data>
    </field>
    <field name="Channel_1">
        <data>Arts in Education</data>
    </field>
    <field name="Channel_2">
        <data>Early Childhood Learning</data>
    </field>
    <field name="Channel_3">
        <data/>
    </field>
    <field name="Channel_4">
        <data/>
    </field>
    <field name="Name_Community">
        <data>classroommanagement</data>
    </field>
    <field name="Webinars_COMMUNITIES::Name_Long">
        <data>Classroom Management for Early Learning</data>
    </field>
    <field name="_ID_Community">
        <data>.5a1dcfde</data>
    </field>
</record>
```

If I use that RegExp at the tester with that string it correctly parses and I am able to find the return value for that field as the 2nd element of the .exec Array result:

```
https://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/story.php?title=quiz-18-classroommanagementwebinar20161114_3WO
```

But sometimes, depending on some reason I can't fathom, I'm getting null values returned for different fields I'm parsing for. In this case, for field URL_ProfProps.

I'm using the following loop to do an exec on RegExp to find all the values in the record. The function itself is called for each record.

```
function webinarParse(record) {
  var r = new Object();
  var fields = ["Name", "Byline_Presenter", "Date", "URL_On_Demand", "URL_Blog", "URL_ProProfs", "Name_Community", "Webinars_COMMUNITIES::Name_Long", "Channel_1", 
                "Channel_2", "Channel_3", "Channel_4", "_ID_Community"];

  for (f=0; f<fields.length; f++) {
      var re = new RegExp('<field name="' + fields[f] + '"><data>(.+?)<\/data><\/field>');
      var m = re.exec(record);
      if (m == null) {
        r[fields[f]] = "";
      } else {
        if (fields[f] == 'Date') {
            r[fields[f]] = new Date(m[1]);
        }
        else {
            if (m[1].indexOf('<data>') != -1) {
                // greedy match captured from next field when there was no data present
                r[fields[f]] = "";
            }
            else {
                r[fields[f]] = m[1];
            }
        }
      }
  }  
  return r;
}
```

The parameter record is one record from all the XML records I returned.

The Object() r is my return value.

The Array() fields is a list of values I'm parsing for.

In the loop I create a new RegExp for each element of fields to see if there is a value to return for it.

If re.exec(record) is null I just set an empty string for that property in r.

If the field happens to be a date string I set a Date object for that property.

Then I have to be careful because the XML is returning

```
<data />
```

if there is no data, rather than

```
<data></data>
```

So I check for that. In other words, if there is data, there should be a

```
<data>
```

tag. If there isn't, I don't want to grab too much.

I'm logging the parsing of each record and it works about 1250 times out of 1280 times. But for some records, one or two of the fields are not parsing, even though I confirmed there is data there in the XML itself.

The example above is one that does seem to parse correctly at the tester page, but in my loop the value for URL_ProPofs is returning a null value.

Any thoughts about my RegExp or loop doing this? I just can't figure out why it sometimes just doesn't find the value.

Thanks.

Comment: Without even reading the full question, I would caution you against using regex to parse XML.  Instead, just use an XML parser.

Comment: Never use dot matching patterns with mark-up languages. Never rely on regex when parsing (X)HTML.

Comment: But there was an accepted answer for this that does that at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341421/with-regex-how-do-i-match-between-an-xml-tag-multiple-times and I am just following that lead.

Comment: @DougLerner: An accepted answer may often be a wrong answer. I fixed one of my 2-year old answer some days ago that did not make sense, but was accepted. If you see `.*?` / `.*` or `.+?` / `.+` in a regex that is meant to parse HTML, know it is already unsafe if there is context on both sides, as in your case. Because `.` matches `<` and `>` and any char other than line break chars. More, `<tag>(.*?)</tag>` regex might freeze your code execution in case the text is huge and there is `<tag>` with no `</tag>` in the text (when HTML is broken).

Comment: Quoting the old joke, if you ask what shoe to use to drive a nail you won't get useful information anyway.

Comment: This is new information pertinent to my original question. I don't know why my parser can't handle this, but after comparing things before and afterwards (when I got parsed results and when I didn't) it became obvious what the cause was. The data that was not found had a newline (return) at the very end. For some reason my parser can't find the value in that case. If I deleted the newline in the source data being returned it parses just fine. I would prefer to fix my current parser to allow cases like that. I am sure there are no non-closed tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer : use XPath/XQuery to query and access data in an XML document, it will give you much more flexibility and get rid of the specific cases like  plus they have been designed for that purpose.

As for the regex, `'.'` doesn't match new lines, so you need to add `\r` and `\n` and also add matching for whatever might be between `<field...>` and `<data...>` as well as between `</data>` and `</field>`.

With all that you'll end up with a regex like this

```
<field name="URL_ProProfs">[\s\n\r]*?<data>((?:.|[\n\r])*?)<\/data>[\s\r\n]*?<\/field>
```

Here is a working example : https://regex101.com/r/07xgks/4 but keep in mind that this will only work as long as you don't have data nested in data, the xml is valid and so on...

Comment: Thank you. I believe that works. In some parts of your regex it may even be overkill, but I have tested it and it seems to work both at the testing site and when I replace it in my own code. I will check out XPath/XQuery and see if it is usable in my system. But for the meanwhile your new expression works, and is even (mostly) comprehensible to me. In this particular case I definitely don't have nested data and I am guaranteed valid XML. So thank you.

Comment: I have a quick question about your solution, which does work. We can change to private conversation if you prefer. 

I understand the \s\n\r]*? part before the data tag and after the /data tag. Those are the parts which are probably overkill for my case, but they don't hurt for sure. And I understand the [\n\r])*? expression inside the data field. And I know the | is OR. 

But what does the ?:. expression mean? I know the period there is for any character except newlines. And ? is to prevent greedy matches. But I don't understand ?:. and the purpose of the : colon. Thanks.

Comment: The `?:` indicates a non capturing group to the regex, basically it indicates that `(?:.|[\n\r])` it is because otherwise you'd get an extra group with the last character of the match in it because of the `|`. Now that I reread my answer, I think you can simplify to `<field name="URL_ProProfs">[\s\S]*?data>([\s\S]*?)<\/data>[\s\S]*?<\/field>`. The `[\s\S]*?` will match any number of whitespace `\s`or non-whitespace `\S` as few times as possible.

Comment: Thanks for the addition explanation. I think I understand. For your new version you mean `<field name="URL_ProProfs">[\s\S]*?<data>([\s\S]*?)<\/data>[\s\S]*?<‌​\/field>` right? In your comment you didn't have a `<` before the `data>`.